# It shows all imports in imports declaration are unused in react native

Tags: react-native

```
Import React, {Components} from 'react';
```

This was not working and components fields is unusable.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing it the wrong way. The correct way is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```